# Why is the execution of the code skipping the 1st statement of "food is on the table'?

Tags: java

```
public class ControlFlow {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Are you hungry?\n");
    String answer = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    if(answer == "yes") {
        System.out.println("Food is on the table!");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Not hungry!\n");
     }

  }

}
```

I tried with boolean variable too. It did not help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  Was I comparing the Object with "yes"? I had to compare charSequence. Is there any easier way to compare that?

Comment: What if I entered if(input.nextLine() == "yes"?

Comment: This would result in the same behavior. You need to compare the content of the strings not the string references.

Comment: Yeah, the statement became false. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried that with if(input.nextLine().contains("yes)). It works.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the content of the strings with:

```
"yes".equals(answer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you please tell me what is happening in that line?

Comment: Did you read the answer I linked in the comments? There is everything explained...